# Classical wave equation and relativity

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, waves, kinematics, lorentz-symmetry

Let it be $f=f(r,t)$ any function representing the "shape" or "outline" of an object.  In classical physics $f$ obeys the "classic" wave equation.

\begin{equation}
\frac{∂^2f}{∂t^2}-v^2\nabla^2 f=0
\end{equation}

If one imagines the object to be a pool ball then $f$ would *precisely* describe the translational motion of the ball to right or left with velocity $v$. However, the **relativistic** form of this *exact* equation (with $0\leqslant v \leqslant c$) do not exists, since:

1. If a phenomenon obeys classic wave equation then $v$ must be equal in all reference frames, which obvious is not the case of a pool ball.
2. Considering previous paragraph (paragraph 1.) and the postulate that the speed of light must be equal on all reference frames, follows that classic wave equation holds only in those cases where $v=c$ (Maxwell equations for example).

**My question is:** Is there a problem with my reasoning and wave equation holds *as it is*. If not, what is the equivalent relativistic form of this equation.

Comment: Have you tried searching for "relativistic wave equation"?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, and you have caused much confusion. Ask a clear question

Comment: As I understand it : for a matter wave the transversal speed has to be relativistic, hence the time should to be replaced by proper time by multiplying by $(1-\dot{y}^2/c^2)^{-1/2}$ so : $v^2\partial_{xx}y-\partial_{tt}y\mapsto v^2\partial_{xx}y-(1-\dot{y}^2/c^2)^{-1}\partial_{tt}y+1/c^2\dot{y}^2\ddot{y}(1-\dot{y}^2/c^2)^{-2}$ ?? Is it the question ?

Comment: If one sees like this then it yields an infinite series of space-time transformations and wave equation by iteration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The premise that $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial t^2}-v^2 \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}=0$ implies anything about what transformation to use is false.

If these were surface waves on water in a Newtonian world, then the correct transformation to use would in fact be a Galilean transformation, and you'd get a wave equation + a transport term. Plug in $\bar{f}(x+u t,t)=f(x,t)$ to see that here, where a subscript x denotes differentiation with respect to the first argument and subscript t with respect to the second argument:
$$\bar{f}_{tt}-(v^2-u^2) \bar{f}_{xx}+2u\bar{f}_{xt}=0$$

If these were surface waves on water in a relativistic world, then the correct transformation to use would be a Lorentz transformation. If $v<c$, then this would transform weirdly. Plug in $\bar{f}(\gamma x+\gamma u t,\gamma t+\gamma u x/c^2)=f(x,t)$ to find:

$$\frac{c^4 - u^2 v^2}{c^4-u^2 c^2} \bar{f}_{tt}+2  u \frac{c^4 - v^2c^2}{c^4- u^2c^2}\bar{f}_{xt}-c^2 \frac{v^2 c^2-u^2c^2}{c^4-u^2 c^2}\bar{f}_{xx}=0$$

It just so happens that if $v=c$, this simplifies to $\bar{f}_{tt}-c^2 \bar{f}_{xx}=0$.

Mathematically, the Lorentz transformation with "speed of light" $v$ is a symmetry of the partial differential equation. Physically, that doesn't prove that the symmetry is the correct one to use. All three partial differential equations here are the correct ones to use in one context or another.

I'm not a good historian of physics, but I believe this is what Einstein is credited with over Lorentz. It was clear for a while that mathematically, Maxwell's equations are invariant under a Lorentz transformation. What Einstein did is give the correct physical interpretation.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the **relativistic** form of this *exact* equation (with $0\leqslant v \leqslant c$) do not exists, since:
>
> 1. If a phenomenon obeys classic wave equation then $v$ must be equal in all reference frames, which obvious is not the case of a pool ball.
> 2. Considering previous paragraph (paragraph 1.) and the postulate that the speed of light must be equal on all reference frames, follows that classic wave equation holds only in those cases where $v=c$ (Maxwell equations for example).

It's not clear to me what you mean by *relativistic form of the wave equation*:
\begin{equation}
\frac{∂^2f}{∂t^2}-v^2\nabla^2 f=0.
\end{equation}

If you mean the form of the equation that is consistent with the special theory of relativity, then the thing to bear in mind is that the form is not important; this equation can be consistent with the special theory of relativity even if $v$ depends on the frame, provided $f$,$v$ are correctly transformed.

In any given frame the pattern has shape and velocity that are constant in time, so the pattern can be expressed as function of $\mathbf x - \mathbf v t$:

$$
f(\mathbf x,t) = \Phi(\mathbf x - \mathbf vt)
$$

Function $f(\mathbf x,t)$ solves the wave equation, for any function $\Phi$. 
Uniformly moving rigid pattern is uniformly moving and rigid in all inertial frames. In non-relativistic theory the pattern $\Phi$ is the same in all inertial frames. In a relativistic theory it is not, since it undergoes the Lorentz contraction.

This means that in order to use the wave equation to describe the pattern in a different reference frame, one has to use appropriate $\Phi$ and $v$ . If the pattern is moving with constant velocity and the shape does not change, this is always possible.

Comment: If one starts with equation 
\begin{equation}
\frac{∂^2f}{∂t^2}-v^2 \frac{∂^2f}{∂x^2}f=0
\end{equation}
after lorentz transformation, becomes 
\begin{equation}
\frac{∂^2f}{∂t’^2}-v^2 \frac{∂^2f}{∂x’^2}f=0
\end{equation}
 being $v$ the same in both systems and not 
\begin{equation}
\frac{∂^2f}{∂t’^2}-v’^2 \frac{∂^2f}{∂x’^2}f=0
\end{equation}
This is the reason why I said Classic Wave Equation *as it is* only applies to those phenomena moving with the speed of light. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Why do you think $v$ and $f$ do not change under the Lorentz transformation? I think they do, since shape and velocity of the object are different in different frames.

Answer (score 0):

Your ball does not obey a classic wave equation even though its outline moves with constant speed. You would at least have to the consider Schroedinger's equation for the wave function. This, however, is not a wave equation but has a first order derivative with respect to time and its solutions do not preserve shape in time.

Your ball is simply an extended object moving at speed v relative to its inertial reference frame. If you measure it in a different inertial reference frame you just have to use the Lorentz transformation for coordinates and time. So you get, e.g. a longitudinal diameter contraction and the speed adds to the reference frame speed according to the velocity addition of special relativity.

When you look at the general solution of classical (sub c) wave propagation in a reference frame according to you wave equation, you simply apply the Lorentz transformation to obtain the shape and time behavior in a different reference frame.

Comment: Could you enlight me on why ball's translation do not obey this equation. **My reasoning is:** Let it be a particle moving with constant speed. If one solves Newton’s second law with $F=0$, then you end up with $r=vt$ or $r-vt=0$. However this is just the solution for a point object of the wave equation which general solution is $f(r-vt)$ (considering just the movement to right). Thank you.

Comment: First, you need only Newton's first law to get r=vt for a point particle. Then, when you have a mathematical solution to the generic wave equation that happens also to have a wave velocity v, that does not imply that there is a physical connection between the mathematical wave and the mass poin, or for that matter your pool ball. Third there is no problem whatsoever in observing a wave with velocity v in an inertial system A in another inertial system B which has a relative velocity to A. The velocity v' and the shape of the wave f(x'-vt') will be given by the Lorentz transformation.

Comment: You need not to find any "relativistic wave equation". The classical wave equation works for system A and the description of the wave in B follows from A. I do not understand what you mean  by point 1, that a classical wave  velocity v should be the same in all reference frames. This happens only for v=c and the consequence is the Special Theory of Relativity and the Lorentz transformation.  You find the Lorentz transformation between A and B here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity.

Comment: If you checkout this link (http://alumnus.caltech.edu/~dif/WaveEqnInvar/main.html) about invariance of the wave equation, you’ll notice that if one starts with equation $\frac{∂^2f}{∂t^2}-v^2 \frac{∂^2f}{∂x^2}f=0$, after lorentz transformation, becomes $\frac{∂^2f}{∂t’^2}-v^2 \frac{∂^2f}{∂x’^2}f=0$ being $v$ the same in both systems and not $\frac{∂^2f}{∂t’^2}-v’^2 \frac{∂^2f}{∂x’^2}f=0$. $c$ was used as the wave velocity there, however it is just the normal convention to use $c$ as the wave velocity, not the speed of light. Thanks.

Comment: This nice link shows explicitly that the only linear  coordinate-time transformations that leads to the form invariance of the classical wave equation with the wave velocity c is the family of Lorentz transformations which also contain the velocity c, which experimentally is the speed of light.   You cannot substitute any different velocity (a lower velocity v than the light velocity c) in this derivation because this would formally give  you a Lorentz transformation with a reference velocity v lower  than the light velocity c, which is physically complete nonsense.

Comment: The problem in your reasoning is : The classical wave equation with a wave velocity lower than the light velocity c is not invariant under Lorentz transformations. It is invariant only when  the wave velocity  c equals the speed of light.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what my problem was. If you see the answer I present it points to  it. However, if you review the original question itself, you’ll see that I was *guessing* it in point 2, but I couldn’t continue on a guess, right?. Thanks for all time you’ve spend on this task. Manuel.